# Select features empty OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, wfs, select

I created in OL3 selector elements new.ol.interacion.Select () on a WFS layer, and when I try to take these features returns an empty array.

My intention is to create a json with the selection check the map features.

This is my code:

```
  var Urbana_source = new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
       return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=pucol:Urbana&' +
    'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
    'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
      },
     strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
     maxZoom: 19
     }))

     });

 var urbana_wfs = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: Urbana_source,
 style: new ol.style.Style({

  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
   width: 2
   })
 })
});
 urbana_wfs.set('name', 'urbana');

select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.click
    });
map.addInteraction(select);
//var feature_buff = select.getFeatures();
select.getFeatures().on('change:length', function(e)
{   
    var feature_buff = select.getFeatures();



    var geojson  = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var  json    = geojson.writeFeatures(feature_buff);

    });
```

and image 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think I had some kind of this problem.
Instead of using  `writeFeatures`, iterate through your features and  use the `writeFeature` method.

try something like this:

```
select.getFeatures().on('change:length', function(e)
{   
    var feature_buff = select.getFeatures();
    var geojson  = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var  json    = new ol.Collection();
    for (var i=0;i<feature_buff.getLength();i++){
    json.push(geojson.writeFeature(feature_buff.item(i)))
    }

    });
```

/// ORIGINAL AUTHOR  POST

Still not working, thanks anyway : 
[image]